# SharePoint 2010 Continous Running workflows

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, workflow-settings

I want a workflow to continually run on SharePoint 2010. It is set to send out an email when an expiration day is 30 days out.

I have set a 'yes/no' field to no. When set to yes, it should skip that item. I published the workflow, and no stop workflow step. Will it continue to run, or must I do something more?

Comment: Post a screenshot of your workflow

Answer (score 6):

Once the end of the workflow is reached, it's equivalent to using a stop workflow action. The workflow will stop running. If you need to run it again, you'll have to run the workflow every time the item changes, and make sure your workflow changes the item so that the workflow will start again. But it will have to be multiple instances of the same workflow.